# Как правильно завершать приложение?

Tags: c#, wpf

Программа разделена на две части - `Core`(без UI) и `WPF UI`.

В `Core` есть метод `Client.Close()`, который нужно вызывать для корректного сохранения данных.

Аналогичный метод добавился в `WPF` сборке, для сохранения положения окна и прочей мути.

Проблема - для завершения программы есть несколько точек входа:

1. Закрытие основного окна
2. Команда в контекстном меню или где то ещё
3. Критическая ошибка приложения

Как правильно закрывать в итоге? Где должна быть общая точка входа - команда, метод в `WPF`, метод в `Core`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь не может быть универсальной рекомендации, но я опишу как бы делал я.

Во-первых, имеет смысл переключить приложение из режима `ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose"` в `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"`.

Затем, вы подписываетесь на закрытие окон, и по приходу нотификации решаете, хотите ли вы завершить приложение. В случае, если не хотите, вы просто продолжаете работу.

В случае, если вы решили закрыть приложение, вы должны просто вызвать `Client.Close()`, и затем `Application.Current.Shutdown()`.

Таким образом, общая точка выхода должна быть в layer'е бизнес-логики, который будет закрывать модель (`Client.Close()`) и сигнализировать фреймворку об окончании работы. UI закроется сам, он неприхотливый.

Comment: `Application.Current.Shutdown()` вызывает в итоге WPF сборка, правильно понял? А если критическая ошибка в Core, что делать?

Comment: @Monk: Это вызывает та часть, в которой у вас бизнес-логика. Если она в WPF-сборке — значит, WPF-сборка. С критической ошибкой вы просто прямиком попадаете в пункт «В случае, если вы решили закрыть приложение».